# '\\' style printer address on Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, printer, macos-highsierra

My company has poor support for mac. When I try to add a network printer, all my info is that all the printers are under an address like `\\server\allprinters` and I should go there and choose the one that I'd like. The printer doesn't show up automatically, but I would be able to add it via IP address. Is there any way I can add the printer based on this `\\server\allprinters` style address?

Comment: I'd suggest asking on https://apple.stackexchange.com/, however I'm supprised apple doesn't accept the \\server\listofprinters arguments to find printers.

Comment: @djsmiley2k - Mac doesn't use the backslash at all for paths. Can't test here because all the printers are directly on the network, not shared from another machine, but see - https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25395 - the GUI should be able to find it without having to know its address.

Comment: @Tetsujin that looks like an answer to me, post it!. - Lte, if you're given a name like that, all the printers are shared via the server, so you jsut need to get the servers IP address, ping it maybe?

Comment: Yes I've done that, but my WG doesn't show up - this has happened before, and I COULD still add by IP, however, I don't have the IP address in this case...

Comment: did you try just turning the slashes round? //server/allprinters ? It might need a protocol header, smb://server/allprinters but as I say, I can't test because of how the printers are set up here, they're not on shared machines, they're distinct network entities [which just auto-setup easily, very little user-interaction required]

Comment: Do you have access to a Windows machine? You could probably get the printer's IP address by viewing the properties of the printer from there.

Comment: @Tetsujin yes, I did... Turns out you can't get the printer IP, just a server address that then distributes the request when you log in to one of the printers. So I guess this won't work at all, but I've had help from local IT since.